# Passing a String into a Function With GDB

Tags: c++, c++11, gdb, reverse-engineering

So, I have a function with the prototype according to GDB:
`{std::string (std::string)} 0x56027729e545 <function(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >)>` , and I would like to pass a string into it using GDB. To attempt this, I've used the following GDB commands to create a new string on the heap.

```
set $mystr = (std::string*) malloc(sizeof(std::string))
call $mystr->basic_string()
call $mystr->assign("foobar")
call (std::string) function(*$mystr)
```

In the last line, I am getting the error `Couldn't find method std::string::std::string`. Any ideas?

Unfortunately, I can't modify the code to fix this.

Comment: Since the argument is not a reference, it probably tries to create a copy of the string. Thou I'm not sure why it thinks the copy constructor is named `std::string::std::string`.